# Inject externalApi into createListenerMiddleware during runtime

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a situation where my app is initialized from outside, and during initialization, it receives some external API. If the store has already been initialized and createListenerMiddleware has been called, is there any way to inject the received API? Something like setContext in Saga

I've tried calling createListenerMiddleware at runtime inside the initialization function, but then I don't have access to startListening.